# Как узнать размер определенной буквы шрифта или ее пропорцию в Python?

Tags: python, шрифты

В моей программе мне нужно написать в документе Word столько символов, сколько поместится в строке, но шрифт этих символов может быть разным. Как узнать размер каждой буквы? Не могли бы вы сказать мне, какие библиотеки или что-то еще использовать для получения данных шрифтов?

Comment: Переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык

Comment: pyautogui выбираете кликами размер и дальше имитируете нажатие кнопок пишите что нужно. ведь нужно в открытом ворде реализовать или док файл записать ?